# Registered models doesn't show up in admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing a Django website, the directories and files in my project is like this :

```
Badil ->
    Badil ->
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
    book ->
       __init__.py
       admin.py
       models.py
       tests.py
       views.py
```

the file book/admin.py contains :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from book.models import  *

admin.site.register(Subject)
```

and the file book/models.py contains:

```
class Subject(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

but the admin site doesn't show the Subject class in it, it only shows Groups, Users and Sites!

Comment: Is `book` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: OMG, It's not! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `book` wasn't included in `INSTALLED_APPS` !